# How to overwrite previous string output by printf

Tags: c++, string, output

Let's say I've output some string by `printf` as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
....
int main()
{
    ...
    printf("Some string\n");
    ...
    printf("Another some string\n") //I want that this line to overwrite the "Some string", but not have it put below.
    ....
}
```

How it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Some string");
    ...
printf("\rAnother some string")
```

If you output anything in between this won't work of course, more advanced terminal twiddling is beyond the scope of (semi)portable C++ (or C in this case).

Comment: Are you certain that this is portable?

Comment: @BillyONeal No it probably isn't portable, but it should work on most terminals.

Comment: @Dmitrii: I seem to recall some consoles interpreting `\r` as just a newline. But I may be mistaken. +1

Comment: @BillyONeal Ok, but it doesn't work when I've added `\n` to this strings. Why? I'm using linux mint 14 and built-in terminal.

Comment: @Dmitrii: `\r` just moves the cursor to the beginning of the line. When you add a new line, `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of that new line, not the beginning of the `Some string` line.

Comment: @Dmitrii: You can see that behavior if you don't have the newline and make the second string shorter than the first one :)

Comment: Another thing that might work is doing several `\b` (backspace)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the C++ standard doesn't define a way of accomplishing what you want here (beyond the carriage return user657267 posted above). Console manipulation like this is typically accomplished using platform features, such as [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) on Unixes or the [Windows Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073.aspx) or the [console I/O library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) in some compilers.